# Unable to execute any conda command; Error: KeyError('pkgs_dirs'), Reason: image not found

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, conda

FYI i am running everything on macOS 10.15.

Whenever I run any conda command I get the following error (e.g.):

## ERROR REPORT

```
(base) xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx:xxxx xxxx$ conda --version
KeyError('pkgs_dirs')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1124, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 57, in main_subshell
    p = generate_parser()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 41, in generate_parser
    description='conda is a tool for managing and deploying applications,'
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 117, in __init__
    self._subcommands = context.plugin_manager.get_hook_results("subcommands")
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 422, in plugin_manager
    from ..plugins.manager import get_plugin_manager
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/plugins/manager.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import solvers, virtual_packages
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/plugins/virtual_packages/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import archspec, cuda, linux, osx, windows
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/plugins/virtual_packages/cuda.py", line 3, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libffi.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1244, in print_unexpected_error_report
    message_builder.append(get_main_info_str(error_report['conda_info']))
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_info.py", line 236, in get_main_info_str
    info_dict['_' + key] = ('\n' + 26 * ' ').join(info_dict[key])
KeyError: 'pkgs_dirs'
```

`$ /opt/anaconda3/bin/conda --version`

```
environment variables:
conda info could not be constructed.
KeyError('pkgs_dirs')
```

I get this kind of error regardless of what conda-command I use, it doesn't matter if I use `conda create --name new_env_name` or `conda info --envs`. That is why I am also unable to uninstall anaconda and just reinstall it again, as I am also unable to use the conda-commands that have to be used to uninstall anaconda such as: `conda install anaconda-clean`. I also can't open the Anaconda Navigator as it shuts down after a second after I tried to open it.

Prior to this error, when everything was working more or less fine, I found out that for some reason python 2.7.X was installed in my conda env. so I updated conda and then python, becuase prior to this I couldn't run my code due to import errors. After I updated conda the errors I explained above occured and I have the feeling that something is wrong in how my computer installed conda I guess.

I already searched all over google and inside of github repos, but I couldn't find any help, as everything I tried did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is what I found out myself. Apparently what happened when I initially installed anaconda for some reason it was installed in the '~/opt' folder. I don't know why that happened and I think this usually should not be the case. That is why, when I updated conda (and this is only an assumption) the installation was not dealt with correctly and this somehow broke everything.

I tried to remove the anaconda3 folder, but I only had reading rights. In the end my solution was to install miniconda in my actual user directory. I know it is not a pretty solution but now it works again, and I have no idea on how to get rid of the anaconda3 folder in the opt-folder.

Also please keep in mind, if you are running into the same error-messages I did, my solution might not work for you as well, so please don't just follow what I did step for step.